# JSDoc document argument that can only take a value from an enum array

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have checked this site for any answers that might solve my problem, yet none of them covers my case.

I have a function that changes color and takes a `color` argument. That function is supposed to only work on values included in the `COLORS` enum.

```js
/**
 * @enum ???
 * or
 * @typedef ???
 */
const COLORS = ['green', 'yellow', 'red', 'none', null];

/**
 * @param {???} color color value from COLORS array
 */
function changeColor(color) {
  if (!COLORS.includes(color)) return;
  // ...
}
```

How would I properly document a) the enum `COLORS`, and b) the function argument `color` in JSDoc?

Edit: It seems my understanding of `enum` is wrong. By the looks of it an array of literals cannot be considered an `enum`. So if I want to stick with my current implementation, how else would I make clear that `color` can only be a value from `COLORS`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on JSDoc documentation for [@constant](https://jsdoc.app/tags-constant.html), [typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html), for the `constant` you could do something like the example below:

```
/** @constant
    @typedef {Array} COLORS
    @type {Array<?string>}
    @default
*/

const COLORS = ['green', 'yellow', 'red', 'none', null];
```

**PS:** Notice that `?` is used to declare that Array value could be string or null. For more check the `Nullable` type in [@type](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) documentation.

For the `Function`:

```
/**
 * @param {?string} color - The color used, one of {@link COLORS}.
 */
function changeColor(color) {
  if (!COLORS.includes(color)) return;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Given I'd use this, how would I make the connection in the documentation for `@param {??} color`?

Comment: @connexo as i understand you want the documentation to indicate that the value of the `color` parameter has to be a member of the `COLORS` array.

Comment: Yes, and my expectation would be that I can do this within the `{??}` part, not just in the comment.

Comment: @connexo you could use perhaps something shown here https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1073 (in the middle of the page) but it would change your callback a bit.

Comment: So there probably isn't a way to document this properly. I don't want my documentation tool to change how I develop.

Comment: @connexo JSDoc is alibrary for documenting JavaScript. You want to indicate in your documentation that in the method `changeColor` the parameter `color` is a member of the `Array` constant named `COLORS`. So your method actually does this in the first line, it checks if `color` exists in the `COLORS` array. The `@link` indicates in your documentation exactly that fact.